# not able to call 'Saveas' function to save pdf as word through acrobat. throws reflection exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am trying to convert a pdf  to word and save it programitcally through api. I have tried the sample  given in the sdk in the C# samples folder by changing the code from other refrences. However i am getting reflection error as ' Target type doesn't match' . Here is my code

```
AcroPDDoc pdfd = new AcroPDDoc();
pdfd.Open(filename);[enter image description here][1]
Object jsObj = pdfd.GetJSObject();
Type jsType = pdfd.GetType();
//have to use acrobat javascript api because, acrobat
 object[] saveAsParam = { "newFile.docx", "com.adobe.acrobat.docx", "", 
false, false };
jsType.InvokeMember("saveAs", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, jsObj, saveAsParam, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

A dialog box is opened and file to convert will be chosen. As of i know this is a working code for many.What am i doing wrong .Please help.I have Acrobat DC installed on my system.This is my version

Version : Adobe  Acrobat Pro DC 2017.009.20044

Comment: Since you named the variable *jsType* and pass *jsObj* as target instance object for InvokeMember, i assume you want `jsObj.GetType();` instead of `pdfd.GetType();`, or?

Comment: Why are you using reflection, especially if its a public member you have direct access to?  Are you sure that the `saveAs` method exists on the `AcroPDDoc` object?

Comment: i have referred the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341073/how-to-convert-pdf-to-word-using-acrobat-sdk

Answer (score -1):

Convert PDF to Word (.docx) using C#:

```
AcroPDDoc() pdfDoc = new AcroPDDoc();
if (pdfDoc.Open(sourceFileName))
{
    Object jsObj = pdfDoc.GetJSObject();
    Type type = jsObj.GetType();
    object[] saveAsParam = { convertedFilePath, "com.adobe.acrobat.docx" };
    type.InvokeMember(
        "saveAs",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, jsObj, saveAsParam);
}
```