# PDF to Word using Acrobat SDK

Tags: pdf, ms-word, acrobat-sdk

OS: Windows Server 2019, Acrobat Pro DC 2021.011

1. My C# program calls Acrobat converting PDF to Word.docx.  I used the code from Jie:
   [How to convert PDF to Word using Acrobat SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341073/how-to-convert-pdf-to-word-using-acrobat-sdk)

```
AcroPDDoc pdfd = new AcroPDDoc();
 pdfd.Open(sourceDoc.FileFullPath);
 Object jsObj = pdfd.GetJSObject();
 Type jsType = pdfd.GetType();
 //have to use acrobat javascript api because, acrobat
 object[] saveAsParam = { "newFile.doc", "com.adobe.acrobat.doc", "", false, false };
 var vrc = jsType.InvokeMember("saveAs",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,null, jsObj, saveAsParam, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Every few days, the function does not create the word file and returns NULL: "var vrc = jsType.InvokeMember".  Identifying the last good date Acrobat successfully created the docx file, I restore the Server from Backup.  The Acrobat function works.

> What may be causing this problem?

2. In the same StackOverflow post, Subhobroto posted WinPython code to convert PDF to Word.   Using Python 10.3.2, Error

```
avDoc = Dispatch("AcroExch.AVDoc") # Connect to Adobe Acrobat

# Open the input pdf file
ret = avDoc.Open(pdfFN)

# Python Error 
File "<COMObject AcroExch.AVDoc>", line 2, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)
```

> What is the correct code?

Thanks for help.

Comment: 1) I'll look at resources.  Thx.  2) More testing results.  On a 2nd VM, I ran the same program. right after a booting the VM.  The first time the program runs, same problem - NULL is returned and no Word file.

Comment: Per Adobe, Acrobat Pro DC is supported on servers.  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/system-requirements.html     Windows 11 (64 bit), Windows 10 (32 bit and 64 bit) version 1809 or later, Windows 8, 8.1 (32 bit and 64 bit)†, Windows 7 SP1 (32 bit and 64 bit), or Windows Server - 2008 R2 (64 bit), 2012 (64 bit), 2012 R2 (64 bit)†, 2016 (64 bit), or 2019 (64 bit)

Comment: KJ Just going down the debug rabbit hole and appreciate the help.  Fact I forgot to mention: I can always run the Acrobat DC app and Export to Word docx file.  Even when the C# program fails, manually running the App successfully creates the Word.docx file.